# 'String' is not convertible to 'Int'

Tags: swift, int, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to create an app that will display the time in format HH:MM:SS.

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute |                       
.CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitSecond,
fromDate:      date)
let hour = Int(components.hour)
let minutes = Int(components.minute)
let second = Int(components.second)
let col = ":"
let time = (hour+col+minutes+col+second)
```

On line
    "let time = (hour+col+minutes+col+second)"
I keep getting the error "'String' is not convertible to 'Int'"
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Also, `components.hour` &co are already of type `Int` - no need to use `Int(components.hour)`.

Comment: And in `calendar.components(...)` you need only specify the components that are actually used (hour, minute, second).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're trying to add (aka, use `+`) `String` and `Int` instances together.

You could instead use string interpolation:

```
let time = "\(hour):\(minutes):\(second)"
```

or better yet, learn about `NSDateFormatter`, which handles this much better:

```
let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("HH:mm:ss", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())

let time = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```